# VBA - find certain value in table and copy belows data until it will find empty cell (inner .find function)

Tags: vba, excel, loops, foreach

I would like to ask you for a help with below's task.

I have source data:
[image]
 ,which are not aligned to table. I would need to find a text (header - e.g. Toimipiste ja uuni) and rows (Columns - B, C, D, E, F), which are below's the searched cell (Toimipiste ja uuni) and paste them on different Sheet. Then search down and do again until the page with data will be ended and data should be pasted chronologically as it is reached.

I already have code, which do the job correctly, but only if below the header is only 2 rows to copy (or static number of rows to copy).

The code, what I have so far is:

```
Private Sub Search_FJ()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngCopy As Range, aCell As Range, bcell As Range
    Dim strSearch As String

    strSearch = "Toimipiste ja uuni"

    Set ws = Worksheets("INPUT_2")

    With ws
        Set aCell = .Columns(2).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            Set bcell = aCell

            If rngCopy Is Nothing Then
                Set rngCopy = .Range(.Cells(aCell.Row + 1, 2), .Cells(aCell.Row + 2, 6))
            Else
                Set rngCopy = Union(rngCopy, .Range(.Cells(aCell.Row + 1, 2), .Cells(aCell.Row + 2, 6)))
            End If

            Do
                Set aCell = .Columns(2).FindNext(After:=aCell)

                If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                    If aCell.Address = bcell.Address Then Exit Do

                    If rngCopy Is Nothing Then
                        Set rngCopy = .Range(.Cells(aCell.Row + 1, 2), .Cells(aCell.Row + 2, 6))
                    Else
                        Set rngCopy = Union(rngCopy, .Range(.Cells(aCell.Row + 1, 2), .Cells(aCell.Row + 2, 6)))
                    End If
                Else
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
        Else
            MsgBox SearchString & "NOT FOUND"
        End If

        '~~> I am pasting to Output sheet. Change as applicable
        If Not rngCopy Is Nothing Then rngCopy.Copy Sheets("OUTPUT_2").Cells(2, 6)
    End With
End Sub
```

I dont know, how to correct the code, that it will take into account, that below the header could be sometimes 2 rows, sometimes 4 rows,... and I would need to copy them all. Its always ended by empty rows as you can see on the screen below:

[image: Code samples 2]

The line, which I am struggling with is:

```
Set rngCopy = .Range(.Cells(aCell.Row + 1, 1), .Cells(aCell.Row + 2, 7))
```

Since the part will copy 2 rows (always). I guess that there should be inner `.find` function, which will search for the header (firstly) and then for the empty cell (secondly), but dont know, how to do that.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do the following: Write a list of steps you want your code to do. List all the steps required for your code to do exactly what you want it to do. Use bullet points for that. Tell us the exact point where you are stuck. Do not post these here in the comments, update your question instead and write a small comment as soon as you have done it, so people get notified.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for you advice. I've already updated the questions with steps. Hope, that its more clear now.

Comment: Good update! You still need to tell us the line of code you are stuggling with.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and inclination to help me with describing the issue :). You were absolutely right, that it looked like I want the whole code, not just help with part of it.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to copy a range of cells, starting at a specific cell and ranging until the last cell with data in it?
[This article](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4438-excel-loop-until-blank.html) covers that task and should give you a good start.

Feel free to ask again if you get stuck at a **specific line** within your code.

Edit: Updated link according to your edits. The `.Select` statements are purely for showcasing and should not be kept in the final version of your code.

Comment: Thanks David. I've checked the article and tried to use it on my code, but no luck with it. I am not able to use the way, that it will find the header, then checked and copy all rows below, which contain data, until the cell is empty and then continue in searching the header... (the process above should repeat until it is all done - whole sheet has been searched, copied and pasted).

Comment: Again: go through your code step by step until you understand each line of code. If you have a question to specific parts of your code, just ask here and we will be glad to help. Just don't expect us to write your code for you. [This](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) excellent article will give you a good idea on how to work on your code.

Comment: I understand the code :) and the line, which I'm struggling with is this - Set rngCopy = .Range(.Cells(aCell.Row + 1, 2), .Cells(aCell.Row + 2, 6)). It took 2 below rows, but I would like to change it the way, that it will search until "value" will be founded. I cant find any clue how to do that (formula or at least some advice, which will described how to do function find until...). I dont want to anyone to write me a whole code, I just wanted to help with this part, at least advise, where should I look at. The article, which you've sent me, does not speak about it. But thank you anyway.

Comment: Perfekt! Adjust your question and the title to contain that specific question and trim down your code to the lines in question. This will greatly improve the odds of getting an answer.